# Chess in C: Negamax implementation works but sometimes doesn't spot mates in 1

Tags: c, chess

I implemented negamax with alpha beta pruning and quiscence search and it seems like it works... except for sometimes the computer lets me mate in 1, even though there were moves that it could've done to prevent it (this happened at depth 4, where it absolutely should've been spotted). I'd really appreciate it if someone more experienced could look at my code and perhaps see something I haven't:

```
static double alphaBetaMax(double alpha, double beta, int depthleft, game_t game, bool player)
{
move_t *cur;
move_t *tmp;
double score = 0;
    bool did_move = false;

cur = getAllMoves(game, player); //getAllMoves initilizes a global list of moves, firstMove
if(cur == NULL) /*  check mate*/
    return -9999999*(player*2-1);
tmp = firstMove;
firstMove = 0;

while (cur != NULL)
{
    game_t copy;
    if(depthleft<=0 && !isCapture(game, cur)) { /* Quiescence search */
            cur = cur->next;
                continue;
    }
            did_move = true;
    copyGame(game, &copy);
    makeMove(&copy, *cur);
    firstMove = NULL;
    score = -alphaBetaMax(-beta, -alpha, depthleft - 1, copy, !player);
    if(board_count > MAX_BOARDS)
      break;

    freeGame(copy);
    if(score > alpha)
      alpha = score;

    if (beta <= alpha)
      break;
    cur = cur->next;
}
firstMove=tmp;
freeMoves();

    if(!did_move)
       alpha = evaluate(game)*(player*2-1);
return alpha;
}

move_t* getBestMove(game_t game, int player, unsigned int depth) // initial call
{
move_t *cur = NULL, *best = NULL;
move_t *tmp;
double alpha = -DBL_MAX, score = 0;
freeMoves();
firstMove = NULL;
cur =  getAllMoves(game, player);
tmp = firstMove;
firstMove = 0;

while (cur != NULL)
{
    game_t copy;
    copyGame(game, &copy);
    makeMove(&copy, *cur);
    firstMove = NULL;
    score = -alphaBetaMax(-DBL_MAX, -alpha, depth-1, copy, !player);
#ifdef PRINT_SCORES
    printf(" <%c,%d> to ", cur->x1 + 'a', cur->y1 + 1);
    printf("<%c,%d>", cur->x2 + 'a', cur->y2 + 1);
    printf(" - score %f\n", score);
#endif
    freeGame(copy);

    if(board_count > MAX_BOARDS)
      break;

    if (score > alpha) {
      alpha = score;

      if (best != NULL) {
        best->next = NULL;
        free(best);
      }
      best = copyMove(*cur);
    }
    cur = cur->next;
}
firstMove = tmp;
freeMoves();

if(board_count > MAX_BOARDS) {
  free(best);
  return 0;
}
return best;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately, it seems that you've misunderstood what this site is about. It appears the code you posted is broken. -- "it seems like it works... except for sometimes" -- We only deal with working code here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code implements incorrectly in many areas, such as q-search, evaluation and the search algorithm itself. For example, your qsearch isn't correct. You're supposed to get a standpat score, then generate all capture and non-quite moves. Use those moves recursively into qsearch.

But most **importantly**, the score that you return for the checkmate is wrong. In nega-max, the checkmate score must and must be returned relative to the player for the turn. That is, you must return **a negative value** for the mate.

Your code

> return -9999999*(player*2-1);

would return a positive value if player is false (false == 0). Read nega-max in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax. Do you see

> bestValue := -∞

in the algorithm? You don't care who the turn it is, you have to return a negative value for the mate.